# Different print page from mobile and computer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, media-queries

I have a page to check users.
However, when printing from a mobile phone, the page is different.

look at the picture :
[in Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRVtA.png)
[in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjXoU.jpg)

```
 @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #F7CAC9;
    }

    @media print {
        #hid {
            display: none;
        }
 }
```

I want the page to be smaller on mobile
Are there solutions?

Comment: The best way to ensure *consistent* printing is to generate a PDF.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: Well did you account for all the style differences in your print stylesheet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hello this must be coding mistake and if you share the code with the css in it will be easier to debug However, making sure you have the correct CSS for printing can often be tricky. Several things can be done to avoid the difficulties you are having. First, separate all your print CSS from your screen CSS. This is done via the `@media print` and `@media screen`.

Often times just setting up some extra `@media print` CSS is not enough because you still have all your other CSS included when printing as well. In these cases you just need to be aware of CSS specificity as the print rules don't automatically win against non-print CSS rules.
you can use some of js libraries to convert html to pdf like below i hope you found this answer helpful

HTML Code:

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- HTML contnet goes here -->
</div>

<div id="elementH"></div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var elementHTML = $('#contnet').html();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});

// Save the PDF
doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use device specific @media tags and apply any width/height/display etc css options within that css block.

```
/* On screens that are 600px or less,*/
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     #hid {
      width: VALUE HERE;
      max-width: VALUE HERE;
      display: VALUE HERE;
      }
    }
```

Change the values to support your needs.

Comment: `@media screen` won't have any impact in print mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can define different styles for different page sizes. You need to specify the page size you want for mobile.

```css
/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
@media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
  @page {
     margin: 3cm;
  }
 }

/* style sheet for "letter" printing */
@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
  @page {
  margin: 1in;
  }
}
```

**Reference:** https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#page-size-media-query